# Application breaks after assembly of stream

Tags: json, exception, xamarin.forms, stream, break

I have created an app which should display the JSON dataset that I have in root in a listview. I have binded everything correctly. After the user logs in, it should be redirected to HomePage where I should display the list, but it breaks. I tried the debugger and as I understand, the JSON file is not assembled to Stream, here is the created code:

namespace Mixed2.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
public HomePage()
{
InitializeComponent();
GetJsonData();
}

```
         void GetJsonData()
    {
       string jsonFileName = "region.json";
      RegionList ObjContactList = new RegionList();
       var assembly = typeof(HomePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
      using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
          var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list  
          ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionList>(jsonString);
       }
        //Binding listview with json string   
       listviewRegions.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.regionData;
   }

   private void RegionTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        // cast the tapped item to the correct type
      var region = (RegionData)e.Item;

       Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(region));
   } 
}
```

}

The part that the application breaks is when it is entering :

```
 using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
```

The error message I get:
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'`

Anyone any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the InnerException of the TargetInvocationException?  Is `stream` null?  Have you verified that the file has the correct content type and you are using the correct naming convention?

Comment: @Jason Yes stream is null

Comment: OK, then figure out why that is.  See the other questions I asked above.  This is basic debugging

Comment: I am very new to this and it is a bit difficult to me. How you suggest me to proceed? Is there a way to send you the project in private (if its okay from you) in order to have a look about my problem?

Comment: if you post it somewhere I'll take a quick look.  But generally, loading a resource from an assembly is very well documented.  It is a basic C# operation that has nothing specific to do with Xamarin.  I'd suggest searching for other questions that have to do with the same problem and see how they were solved.

Comment: Okay, I will do some research in other topics. If I can't find a solution, then I will post it somewhere and leave you a comment here. Thank you for your guidance

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add [SOLVED] to the title or edit a solution into the question body. If you've found a solution you want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @KenWhite I am really sorry for this, I am new in the community. I didn't see the 'Answer your question' I will post the answer there as I should from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem was: `setting my JSON file to embedded resource from properties.` I turned it to embedded resource and the application worked fine and my data were displayed in the home page, as they should.